# How to switch my primary AMD graphics card

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I bought a new laptop (HP Pavilion 15-ab111la Notebook) with 1TB HDD, 12GB RAM, AMD A-10 CPU and Radeon R8 graphics card.
I started to download and install games from my steam account and noticed most of them freeze every 2-10 seconds.

Checked my devices administrator, as well as AMD Radeon Graphics settings utiliy and it says I have a R6 primary graphics card and a R8 linked graphics card.

[image: Primary R6, Linked R8]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

I tried configuring AMD Radeon Dual Graphics to use both of them on my games but it only seemed to end in an even worse performance.
When configuring graphics or 3d accelerator on a game like Skyrim here:

[image: Like Skyrim here]

I can only choose the R6 card (500MB of dedicated memory) and never the R8 card (2GB of dedicated memory) so I can't run any game properly (Not even Age of Empires, for God's sake!!!)
Is there a way to set my R8 card as primary and default graphic card instead of the R6?  How can I take advantage of my AMD Radeon R8 graphics card?

Comment: Your specs say it has only i graphics adapter...http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-15-ab100-Notebook-PC-series/8499302/model/9033434/document/c04792142/

Comment: There was a graphics driver update Jan 8, 2016.  http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-15-ab100-Notebook-PC-series/8499302/model/9033434

Comment: I would also check your Power Options settings in control panel, set it to High Performance, it may be hidden in a drop down, click the V next to "show additional plans"

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a laptop with crossfire capability
desktop only
the only exception is MAYBE the alienware type boxes that allow an external graphic card to be attached
like these:
https://www.computershopper.com/feature/2017-guide-the-best-external-graphics-card-boxes-egpus

maybe its dual graphics
in your case, i suspect its a driver error. 
do a clean install:
https://community.amd.com/thread/180667

then download the newest drivers